# Javascript function getBoundingClientRect() returns weird results (top = 0) on mobile devices, when keyboard appears

Tags: javascript, android, ios

We encountered a problem, when positioning the DIV using JavaScript getBoundingClientRect() function.

While everywhere it returns fine answers, it will stop giving reliable results on mobile devices (android as well as iPhone). As the keyboard appears, the window.resize event is triggered, but getBoundingClientRect() for an element returns top = 0, and that is not, what i expected.

Has anyone crossed over the same problem or even solution?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem, it was plain and simple, but I have overlooked it at the first place.
There were two DIVs, that matched the querySelector and one of the DIV was hidden. That DIV returned top = 0.